# Salt-Stack init process after package is installed

Tags: saltstack, aide

Installing AIDE needs to follow by a init proces.

`aide:`
`pkg:`
`- installed`

Now the following commands need to run only once:
`/usr/sbin/aide --config=/etc/aide.conf --init`
`mv -f /var/lib/aide/aide.db.new.gz /var/lib/aide/aide.db.gz`

How to manage this in a state file?

Answer (score 1):

I usually do something like this:

```
run aide once after installation:
  cmd.run:
    - name: usr/sbin/aide --config=/etc/aide.conf --init mv -f /var/lib/aide/aide.db.new.gz /var/lib/aide/aide.db.gz
    - unless: test -e /var/lib/aide/aide.db.gz
    - require: aide
```

Untested, obviously, but you get the idea. The cmd.run state will only run if the command passed to the unless option returns a non-zero exit status.

[cmd.run state documemtation](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.cmd.html#salt.states.cmd.run)